# Unable to graph this circular equation using Sympy

Tags: python

For some reason I am unable to graph the function f over the interval [-70,70]. F is the cross-section of a tank that I need to find the volume for.

```
from sympy import *

from scipy.integrate import quad

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt     

f = 0.0002017404542*x**2 +((0.0001303290910*y**2)/0.9520444748+a*y)-1


def integrand(a,y):

    a = 0.005

    x = abs(((1-((0.0001303290910*y**2)/0.9520444748+a*y))*(1/0.0002017404542)*pi))**(0.5)

    return x

volume = quad(integrand,-70,110,args=(a))

#m = arange(0,0.02)
print(volume)

m = arange(-100,100,1)


x = arange(-70,70)

plot(x,f)
```

---

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-434-24ff72906e56> in <module>()
     31 x = arange(-70,70)
     32 
---> 33 plot(x,f)
     34 #plot(a,volume(x))
     35 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sympy/plotting/plot.py in plot(*args, **kwargs)
   1289     series = []
   1290     plot_expr = check_arguments(args, 1, 1)
-> 1291     series = [LineOver1DRangeSeries(*arg, **kwargs) for arg in plot_expr]
   1292 
   1293     plots = Plot(*series, **kwargs)

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Edit:

Also when I use the code
    plt.plot(x,f)

I get the following error:

```
ValueError    Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-435-6b2132932858> in <module>()
      3 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
      4 
----> 5 f = 0.0002017404542*x**2 + ((0.0001303290910*y**2)/0.9520444748+a*y)-1
      6 
      7 def integrand(a,y):

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (140,) (10,)
```

Comment: Did you mean `plt.plot(x,f)`?

Comment: @Gabriel When I do plt.plot(x,f) I get a value error: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (140,) (10,)